# How to Display Record Details with Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning-experience, record

I have an apex controller class:

```
public with sharing class CatTrackingController {

    @auraEnabled
public static list<Cats__c> getCats(){
    return [ SELECT Id, Cat_Name__c, Cat_Breed__c, Cat_Gender__c, Cat_Nickname__c, Cat_Personality__c
    FROM Cats__c
    ];
}

@auraEnabled
public static Cats__c createCats(string name, string catName, string Nickname, String Breed, String Gender, String Personality){
    Cats__c cats = new Cats__c();
    cats.Name = name;
    cats.Cat_Name__c = catName;
    cats.Cat_Nickname__c = Nickname;
    cats.Cat_Breed__c = Breed;
    cats.Cat_Gender__c = Gender;
    cats.Cat_Personality__c = Personality;
    insert cats;
    return [SELECT Id, Cat_Name__c, Cat_Breed__c, Cat_Gender__c, Cat_Nickname__c, Cat_Personality__c
    FROM Cats__c];
}

}
```

---

and the lightning component page:

```
<aura:component description="CatTracking" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="cats" type="Cats__c[]"/>

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.loadCats}"/>

<div class="slds-align--absolute-center">
    <p class="slds-text-heading--label">Click any Cat to view or edit details</p>
</div>
<div class="slds-align--absolute-center">
    <ui:button aura:id="new" label="Create new Cat" press="{!c.loadNew}"/>
    <br/>
</div>
<table class="myClass slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer">
    <thead>
    <tr class="slds-text-heading--label">
        <th scope="col">
            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Cat Name">Name</div>
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Nickname">Nickname</div>
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Gender">Gender</div>
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Breed">Breed</div>
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Personality">Personality</div>
        </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.cats}" var="cat">

    </aura:iteration>
    </tbody>
</table>
</aura:component>
```

---

### and the component js controller:

```
({
    loadCats : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getCats");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            if(response.getState()==="SUCCESS" && component.isValid()){
                component.set("v.cats",response.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    loadNew : function(component, event, helper) {
        var loadEvent = $A.get("e.c:CatsClickEvent");
        loadEvent.setParams({"new":true});
        loadEvent.fire();
    },
})
```

---

When I add the lightning component to an app in lightning app builder it says there's no data. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you do have cat records right? your aura:component tags are missing, are you invoking the controller?

Comment: I do have cat records and I'm trying to invoke the controller

Comment: your lightning component code is incomplete, please update your post

Comment: oh yeah i see now i didn't copy the whole code, will update

Comment: actually when i edit the whole thing is there but isn't displaying in post but-<aura:component description="CatTracking" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="cats" type="Cats__c[]"/>          ----> that's what's not displaying

Comment: done, edited for you. Fyi, you are still not invoking the controller

Comment: Add this to your controller: ` controller="CatTrackingController"` Also, I noticed that your `@AuraEnabled` annotation has the wrong case - I'm not sure if it's case sensitive - but I'll give you a tip: When you write code, treat it as though it's case sensitive. Your code readability and quality will improve. Apex's case insensitivity is not blanket and it has caused a wave of bad code from people new to the platform. Don't be part of that wave. Be the surfer on it.

Comment: Cassla, did you manage to get your code working?

Comment: Yes, I did get the code working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close to what you are trying to achieve, you need to output that data, You loaded it correctly just forgot to add the `controller` in the component as already suggested by @glls and then output the data inside the `aura:iteration` like this:

```
<aura:component description="CatTracking"
      implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes"
      controller="CatTrackingController"
      access="global">

    <!-- more code -->
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.cats}" var="cat">
        <tr>
            <td>{!cat.Cat_Name__c}</td>
            <!-- more fields here --> 
        </tr>
    </aura:iteration>
    <!-- more code -->
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to invoke the controller in your lightning component, you can refer to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apex_records.htm)

you will notice that the `aura:component` tag should have a `controller` attribute which should be equal to the controller name in order to invoke it.

for example:

Apex Controller:

```
public with sharing class MyObjController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<MyObj__c> getMyObjects() {

        // Perform isAccessible() checks here 
        return [SELECT Id, Name, myField__c FROM MyObj__c];
    } }
```

Component:

```
<aura:component controller="MyObjController"/>
<aura:attribute name="myObjects" type="namespace.MyObj__c[]"/>
<aura:iteration items="{!v.myObjects}" var="obj">
    {!obj.Name}, {!obj.namespace__myField__c}
</aura:iteration>
```

Additionally, take notice of the iteration in the sample provided. For each cat record you have, what do you want the iteration to render in markup?